# How to get first day of previous month Datetime with Dartlang

Tags: dart

I want to get first day of previous month in Dart as DateTime.
Below code **is** working correctly even for **x** = 1 (passing 0 as month)

```
  print(new DateTime(2016,x-1,1));
```

but is it by design or I should not relay on it ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is by design.
The `DateTime` constructor you are using allows overflow and underflow on both days and months. A month value less than one means a month prior to January, which is a month in a previous year. Likewise a day value of less than one is a day in a previous month.